# 'encrypted 'option is deprecated in favor of 'useTLS'

Tags: node.js

i try to run my server.js file via the command line node server.js, but i got this error message and i was unable to resolve it, i use google chrome, I modify my settings tq I deactivated the parmaetree TLS1.0, but without having verro , some one can help ? thanks ,

**server.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Pusher = require('pusher');

const Sentiment = require('sentiment');
const sentiment = new Sentiment();

const pusher = new Pusher({
  appId: process.env.PUSHER_APP_ID,
  key: process.env.PUSHER_KEY,
  secret: process.env.PUSHER_SECRET,
  cluster: process.env.PUSHER_CLUSTER,
  encrypted: true,
});
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  );
  next();
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
app.post('/messages', (req, res) => {
    const { body } = req;
    const { text, id } = body;
    const result = sentiment.analyze(text);
    const comparative = result.comparative;
    const tone =
      comparative >= 0 ? (comparative >= 1 ? 'positive' : 'neutral') : 'negative';
    const data = {
      text,
      id,
      timeStamp: new Date(),
      sentiment: {
        tone,
        score: result.score,
      },
    };
    pusher.trigger('chat', 'message', data);
    res.json(data);
  });
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, it's coming from [this line](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-node/blob/master/lib/config.js#L13). Set `useTLS` instead of `encrypted`.

Answer (score 5):

It means that the 'encrypted' keyword is deprecated and you are gonna have to use 'useTLS' like below:

```
const pusher = new Pusher({
  appId: process.env.PUSHER_APP_ID,
  key: process.env.PUSHER_KEY,
  secret: process.env.PUSHER_SECRET,
  cluster: process.env.PUSHER_CLUSTER,
  useTLS: true,
});
```